# Sum rows together with the same ID but different event logs with conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

A table has 3 different fields, the first being `user_id`, `event_log`, `uploaded_files`.

```
user_id       event_log       uploaded_files
--------------------------------------------
1             0001            1
1             0002            1
1             0003            1
2             0004            5
2             0005            2
2             0006            1
3             0007            1
3             0008            4
```

I am aiming to merge the user_id rows together in one and sum up the uploaded_files column, while implementing conditions such as `total files > 1 and <6`. Ideally I would like this:

```
user_id       total_files
--------------------------
1             3
3             5
```

So far I have only been able to get to:

```
user_id       total_files
--------------------------
1             3
2             8
3             5
```

I have gotten there by using:

```
SELECT user_id, sum(files_uploaded) total_files
FROM my_table
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY user_id;
```

I've tried to add conditions: `ORDER BY user_id WHERE total_files >1 AND total_files <6`, but I am unable to. Is there something that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use aggregate expressions in the `WHERE` clause; for this, you need to use the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT user_id, sum(files_uploaded) total_files
FROM my_table
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING SUM(files_uploaded) > 1 AND SUM(files_uploaded) < 6
ORDER BY user_id;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6b2db06d80bd6343bf6b0217ad0bae47)**

```
user_id | total_files
------: | ----------:
      1 |           3
      3 |           5
```